# Why does -webkit-margin-collapse take the smallest value when there is an h1 inside of the body tag?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I'm just trying to understand the default stylesheet for Chrome.

If you have this html:

`<body><h1>Hello</h1></body>`

By default the `<body>` tag has a `margin` of `8px`, and the `<h1>` tag has a default `-webkit-margin-before` of `0.67 em`, which comes to `21.44px`. Why then does the `<h1>` tag appear to ignore the `21.44px` margin? Margin collapse rules should take the larger of the two margins.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In quirks mode, margin collapsing behaves differently in a variety of situations. In your example, the default top margin of any first child of `body` that has default margins, such as `p` or `h1`, will be ignored. I believe Chrome implements this behavior via the `-webkit-margin-collapse` property (as mentioned in your title); Firefox instead zeroes out the top margin of most `body > :-moz-first-node` elements (see quirk.css).

You'll see the expected behavior when you include a DOCTYPE.